# GitHub Action: Pass npm package output to variable

Tags: node.js, github, npm, github-actions, building-github-actions

I'm having trouble accessing the output of a global npm command in GitHub Actions. Running any global linting npm package (I've tried a few different ones) always exits with: `Process completed with exit code 1.`.

The funky thing is, I can run these bash commands just fine on my local machine.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.13.2

      - name: Install npm package
        run: npm install markdownlint-cli --location=global

      - name: Run standard-markdown
        id: run_md_lint
        run: |
          VAR=$((markdownlint **/*.md --ignore node_modules) 2>&1)
          echo "::set-output name=LINT_RESULT::$VAR"

      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo "Resultes ${{ steps.run_md_lint.outputs.LINT_RESULT }}"
```

The expected output from the run step is logged in the GitHub action logs, but accessing the result and saving it to a variable isn't possible—I'm guessing due to the exit error.

[image]

I should mention that the ultimate goal of this is to capture the output and add it to a comment when a PR is opened.

```
      - name: Add PR comment
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: "${{ steps.run_md_lint.outputs.LINT_RESULT }}"
            })
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

---

### EDIT: IT WORKS!

Thank you so much to @VonC for helping solve my problem. A few notes:

- As explained below, I needed to add `|| true` to the command to return a different exit status.
- `set-output` only works for one-line strings. I needed to replace newlines and carriage returns to save multiple lines.
- The npm package has to be installed with `-g`. `-location=global` does not work.

Here's the working GitHub Action:

```yaml
name: Lint the docs!
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Set up Node.js
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.13.2

      - name: Install markdownlint
        run: npm install -g markdownlint-cli

      - name: Run standard-markdown
        id: run_md_lint
        run: |
          LINT=$(((markdownlint **/*.md --ignore node_modules) 2>&1) || true)
          LINT="${LINT//'%'/'%25'}"
          LINT="${LINT//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
          LINT="${LINT//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
          echo "::set-output name=LINT_RESULT::$LINT"

      - name: Add PR comment
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: `Lint results:
              \`\`\`bash
              ${{ steps.run_md_lint.outputs.LINT_RESULT }}
              \`\`\`
              `
            })
```

Comment: Instead of manually adding PR comments, have you considered problem matchers? E.g. https://github.com/marketplace/actions/problem-matcher-for-markdownlint-cli

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but markdown-lint isn't the only functionality I want to add, so I think it makes sense to stick with the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this thread](https://github.community/t/no-output-on-process-completed-with-exit-code-1/123821/8), try and add `|| true` on the command returning an exit status different from 0 ([illustration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66634171/6309))

Something like:

```
VAR=$(((markdownlint **/*.md --ignore node_modules) 2>&1) || true)
# or
VAR=$(((markdownlint **/*.md --ignore node_modules) || true) 2>&1)
```

That would force GitHub script run step to *not* consider the step as failed.

---

The OP confirms it works with the first syntax:

```yaml
      - name: Install markdownlint
        run: npm install -g markdownlint-cli

     - name: Run standard-markdown
        id: run_md_lint
        run: |
          LINT=$(((markdownlint **/*.md --ignore node_modules) 2>&1) || true)
          LINT="${LINT//'%'/'%25'}"
          LINT="${LINT//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
          LINT="${LINT//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
          echo "name=LINT_RESULT::$LINT" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Add PR comment
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: `Lint results:
              \`\`\`bash
              ${{ steps.run_md_lint.outputs.LINT_RESULT }}
              \`\`\`
              `
            })
```

Note: I have used `$GITHUB_OUTPUT`, since the [command `::set-output` command has now (Oct. 2022) been deprecated](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/).

Comment: Holy guacamole, this was exactly what I needed! I'll edit my original question to include the final code. Thank you so much for your help and enjoy the bounty!